# Is it Ok to leave a guitar with a broken string?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, strings, maintenance, string-instruments

Just broke the high E on my guitar and won't be able to get new strings for about 2 weeks. will leaving it as it is damage the guitar at all?
the guitar is an Ibanez rga42fm with a fixed bridge
All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be just fine for 2 weeks.  You may want to loosen the other strings a bit if they have jumped sharp. (Not as likely with a fixed bridge as it would be with a floating bridge.)

It's actually recommended to reduce the tension on a guitar that will be stored.  For example, [Fender suggests loosening all the strings by two half-steps.](https://www.fender.com/articles/tech-talk/case-closed-storage-tips-to-save-your-guitars#:%7E:text=2%20%2D%20Keep%20the%20string%20tension,lead%20to%20neck%20bowing%20problems.)

Answer (score 2):

Never had any problems leaving one string off for a short time, so I'd say it's o.k. Particularly if the guitar concerned has a trussrod.

There is a way round it, though. Buy more strings than you need at that time - so you'll always have extra for situationss like this. Guitar strings are sacrificial - they're not meant to last as long as the guitar - and remember when changing them, it's best to do it one at a time - so the neck tension stays fairly constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your guitar will not be damaged by leaving it with broken strings.

The tension difference won't have any affect, even for long periods of time. Solid body guitars especially can withstand a very wide range of tension put on them, and less or no tension won't change them at all.